# Specific WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, database

I can't figure this one out.

`$sql = "SELECT id,goodtill FROM table WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";`

However, I want to make sure that when that `$id` is `100` its `goodtill` in the database is `> '0'`.

There are several `$id's` that are `100`. Some of them have `goodtill > '0'` and some them have `goodtill = '0'`. I only want to show the ones that have `goodtill > '0'` And of course I want all other `$id's` that are not `100` to show.

I tried `WHERE id = '$id OR ($id = '100' AND goodtill > '0')` but I am pretty sure it's not how it's done, since it din't do what I wanted it to do.

Comment: `WHERE (id = '100' and GoodTill > '0') or (id = $id)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add conditions (in addition to `id = $id`) for where the ID is not 100, *or* the goodtill is greater than 0.

```
SELECT id,goodtill FROM table
  WHERE id = '$id'
  AND (id != 100 OR goodtill > 0)
  ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

- Given an input `$id` of `9`, this will match all records where `id = 9`. The `where id != 100` is true, and effectively short-circuits the `OR goodtill > 0` check.
- Given an input `$id` of `100`, this will match all records where `id = 100` and `goodtill > 0`. The `id != 100` is false, meaning the `OR goodtill > 0` condition must pass.

Answer (score 0):

And case when $id=100 then goodtill>0 else 1=1.
Instead of the or clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,goodtill FROM table WHERE id = '$id' AND (id != 100 OR (id = '100' AND goodtill > '0')) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: There's no need for `id = '100' AND`, since that's the only alternative to `id != 100`.

Comment: But if you're going to keep it, I suggest adding parentheses to make the grouping obvious. Off the top of my head I'm not sure that the default precedence does what you want.

Comment: Added parentheses for clarity. Need to keep `id = '100' AND` - otherwise it will not work as intended.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work as intended? What combinations of values would cause it to fail?

Comment: See meagar's answer, he gives examples of each case, and shows that it works.

Comment: Although I admit that showing it explicitly does make the logic clearer.